# 'HTMLElement' is undefined in IE8, an alternative?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

Hey all I have methods like this:

```
// Has Class
HTMLElement.prototype.hasClass = function (searchClass) {
    return this.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + searchClass + '(\\s|$)'));
}
```

In IE9 it works fine. In IE8 it gives me undefined... is there a simple work around?

Answer (score 2):

You can't add methods to `HTMLElement.prototype` in older versions of IE if I remember correctly. A simple workaround would be:

```
var hasClass = function (el, searchClass) {
    return el.className.test(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + searchClass + '(\\s|$)'));
};
```

And used like:

```
alert(    hasClass(   document.getElementById('div1'), 'classToCheck'   )    )
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nNdhB/)

You can always add this to the `Object.prototype` object but it's frowned on