# What's IE take on HTMLDocument and HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom

Within javascript's scope, referring  to [`HTMLDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLDocument) or [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLElement) raises error on IE8.

The error I get is "HTMLElement is undefined".

What is the way to have JS interacting with native DOM object of this browser?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868004/htmlelement-is-undefined-in-ie8-an-alternative

Comment: @mplungjan - this is undelated as I am not asking for a given element, rather about the DOM core API.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In IE8 you have to use the `Element` and `HTMLDocument` classes. In IE7... nothing, because IE7 is terrible for standards. You have to rely on jQuery or other frameworks that wrap DOM elements.

In my own framework I make this simple check:

```
var elementPrototype = typeof HTMLElement !== "undefined"
        ? HTMLElement.prototype : Element.prototype;
```

Mind you that it's not a framework for IE7 and lower.

Comment: I just tested is again on IE8 and both, Element and Document are undefined.

Comment: @TzuryBarYochay In IE8, `Element` is defined. If not, that's because you're in compatibility mode. About `Document`, it's actually `HTMLDocument`.